# Тормозит анимация при закрытии клавиатуры

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток.
При закрытии клавиатуры, за ней тянется белый след, все тяжелые процессы вынесены в сервис, ради теста отключал все - и работы с БД и сеть .... тот же результат

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/selection"
              android:textSize="17sp"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:id="@+id/tv_selection" android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_margin_top"
              android:textSize="17sp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/tv_selection"
              android:background="@drawable/edit_location"
              android:id="@+id/tv_show_count_selection"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_margin_top"
              android:text="@string/location_selection"
              android:textSize="17sp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/tv_show_count_selection"
              android:id="@+id/tv_location_selection" android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <AutoCompleteTextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:textSize="17sp" android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_margin_top"
                          android:layout_below="@+id/tv_location_selection"
                          android:maxLines="1"
                          android:completionThreshold="1"
                          android:singleLine="true"
                          android:background="@drawable/edit_location"
                          android:id="@+id/et_location_selection"/>


    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/type_selection"
              android:textSize="17sp" android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_margin_top"
              android:layout_below="@+id/et_location_selection"
              android:id="@+id/textView" android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fultime"
            android:button="@drawable/cb_light"
            android:id="@+id/cb_fultime" android:layout_below="@+id/textView" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/contract"
            android:button="@drawable/cb_light"
            android:id="@+id/cb_contract" android:layout_below="@+id/cb_fultime"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/remotely"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cb_contract"
            android:button="@drawable/cb_light"
            android:id="@+id/cb_remotely" android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/elips"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cb_fultime"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cb_remotely">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/nav_tv_job_count_center"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                />
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/nav_tv_job_count"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/nav_tv_job_count_center"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/job_count"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/nav_tv_job_count_center"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_location"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cb_remotely"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_nav_rating_important"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/item_favorite"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:src="@drawable/ic_nav_rating_important"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="@string/str_favorite"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="3dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/item_favorite"
              android:background="@drawable/edit_location"
              android:id="@+id/tv_line"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_nav_rating_important"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/item_setting"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_line"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:src="@drawable/ic_nav_action_settings"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="@string/str_setting"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Представьте себе процесс:**

```
Клавиатура закрывается плавно( уезжает вниз экрана на определенное количество пикселей в секунду ). Интерфейс же приложения перерисовывается( и, возможно, масштабируется ) в соответствии с новым освобожденным от клавиатуры пространством. Перерисовка происходит быстрее, чем заезжает клавиатура( минимум, в 10 раз ).
```

*Один из вариантов* - у вас на устройстве может стоять кастомная прошивка( не "заводская" ), в которой стандартная клавиатура заменена на более ресурсоемкую( как результат моддинга прошивки ). И поэтому анимированный процесс "уезжания" клавиатуры "жрет" слишком много вычислительных ресурсов. В таком случае попытайтесь заменить клавиатуру или хотя бы как-то кастомизировать.

*Второй вариант* - ищите неровности в своем коде! Порой, находя таковые, удивляешься: как приложение вообще работало и не падало от того же OutOfMemory, например.

Comment: тестировалось на нескольких девайсах, ради теста убирал все тяжелые процессы, нет даже предупреждений потому и странно